# How to display from UILabel html content, images, video in Swift 4

Tags: image, video, webkit, uilabel, swift4.2

How to display from UILabel HTML content from API such as images and video, expect text which I have already done it. Is there a way to fetch from UILabel without using textview or WebKit all the content.

My code is kinda working from the images but the images are huge/cut and also doesn't embed videos from YT or FB

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0Wcv.jpg

```
do {
        if let htmlMessageData = post?.content.data(using: 
String.Encoding.utf16) {
            let layoutMessage = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: 
htmlMessageData, options: 
[NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: 
NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.alignment = .justified

layoutMessage.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, 
value: paragraphStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 
layoutMessage.string.count))
            self.contentLabel.attributedText = layoutMessage
        }
    }
    catch {}
```

Comment: Hi, you got the solution ? I have same problem like this.